# Regex help requested first words in 2 consecutive lines

Tags: regex, line

I need a regex for the following sample text:

```
Doe printing and typesetting industry.
Name Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
```

The regex must result "**Doe**" (which could be any other name or word)  based on fixed "**Name**" string in the line below it. Both words are first in line.

This regex gives me every first word of every line, but need help with the check on "Name":

```
(^\w+)
```

Comment: Try: `(^\w+)(?=.*\nName)`

Comment: Let me see if I understood... You need to match Name, and then the first word of the line behind it? It do you need to match the first two words for the two lines regardless what they are

Comment: Thanks @Poul Bak, your short and sweet suggestion is MONEY!

Comment: In addition to the case, if the first line started with Mr. or Mrs. and I wanted to ignore this, so the match should still be Doe. What would the regex be then? This does not do the trick (?Mr\.|Mrs\.)(^\w+)(?=.*\nName)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
^(\S+)(?=.*\r?\nName\b)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/xZCdbx/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Name                     'Name'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Many ways to Rome I guess. Thx for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(^\w+)(?=.*\nName)
```

Poul Bak
Jan 20 at 23:50